# Mac's strange behaviours, ⌘C not work, holding down ⇧ Shift not do a capital "E" & "mission control" getting activated randomly

Tags: mission-control

⌘C command not copying, holding down ⇧ Shift not do a capital "E" & more than 10 random keys will activate "mission control".

I have Lightroom CC, Overwrite the Preferences of Lightroom didn't help at all.

What can I do?

Comment: What model of Mac, what OS version? Is this problem only in Lightroom, or in all/other applications?

Comment: Also, did anything happen before, like maybe you dropped something on the keyboard, or it got wet?

Comment: iMac Late 2015, the problem with all the applications. i read a comment by someone else in this website who has the same issue and he stated that it is due to lightroom and overwriting the Preferences of Lightroom fixed it. i tried the procedure, but not worked for me.

Comment: Nope droped nothing on the keyboard

Comment: What kind of keyboard? WIred or Bluetooth? Can you temporarily use another (wired) keyboard to check whether the same problems occur there?